# Generate random date but exclude some dates from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, arraylist, random

I have an array called **dates** which contains some dates. I want to exclude those dates and generate a new random date which starts from today.

dates = [20/2/2020,10/2/2019] //**dates needs to be excluded**

So far I have tried,

```
        var new_dif =  Math.random(); //generates random number
        
        var daea = new Date(new_dif); //new random date
        
        alert(daea); //generates new date with year 1970
```

Comment: Option 1: create a loop that retries random values until a non-excluded is rolled. Option 2: if I want a random number between 1 and 10 without 5 and 7 then you basically want to generate a random number between 1 and 8 and if it >=5 then add 1 to it and if it is >= add another 1. That way a 5 is a 6, a 6 is a 8, a 7 is a 9 and a 8 is a 10, you could try to adapt that based on randomly rolling the day since 1970 and excluding some days.

Comment: @luk2302 the comment which I put is giving results like this "Sat Aug 22 1970 22:20:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)". But I want to exclude the other dates which are in array and then generate new date.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [Date](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) and [Math.random](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). The Date constructor will take an integer that represents a unix timestamp. Math.random returns a float from 0-1. There are examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp) that describe how you can create random numbers with a minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create random date from today
2. Have while loop, Check generated already exist in exclude dates array (continue loop until you find date which is not in dates array)

```js
const randomDateFromToday = (exclude_dates, max_days = 365) => {
  const randomDate = () => {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_days) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const dat = new Date(Date.now() + rand);
    return `${dat.getDate()}/${dat.getMonth() + 1}/${dat.getFullYear()}`;
  };
  let rday = randomDate();
  while (exclude_dates.some((date_str) => date_str === rday)) {
    rday = randomDate();
  }
  return rday;
};

dates = ["20/2/2020", "10/2/2019"];
console.log(randomDateFromToday(dates));
console.log(randomDateFromToday(dates));
```

Comment: Straight forward and easy implementation thanks it worked!!!

Comment: There should be some caveats around the use of this function. The *while* loop means it rapidly becomes inefficient as the number of elements in the array approaches the value of  *max_days* and becomes an infinite loop when the number of elements equals `max_days + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this (with a random date setup somewhere in the future one year from now).

```
const now = (new Date()).getTime();
const newDiff = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, 10);
const otherDate = new Date(now + newDiff);
console.log(otherDate);
```

Then you'll need to check with your array of excluded ones and see if they match. If not, then you're good to use it.

Or when using loops:

```js
function getRandomDate() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var newDiff = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, 10);
  var otherDate = new Date(now + newDiff);
  return otherDate;
};



var excludedDates = ['2020-02-20', '2019-02-10'];

var duplicate = true;
while (duplicate) {
  var getMyDate = getRandomDate();
  duplicate = false;
  excludedDates.forEach((excludedDate) => {
    var excludedInMs = (new Date(excludedDate)).getTime();
    if (excludedInMs === getMyDate) {
      duplicate = true;
    }
  });
  if (!duplicate) {
    console.log('while >>>>', getMyDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: and what do you do if they match?

Comment: Then you need to setup my example in a function and rerun it and recheck if the new random date is again matching.

Comment: So Option 1 of my comment on the question: loop until you find a non-conflicting date!?

Comment: Can you help me with the loop? How should I exclude the dates which are there in the dates array.

Answer (score 0):

what if I want to suggest the next date which is not random but the closest one from an array?