# Suggest Next available date(closest) but don't suggest dates which are in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, data-structures, logic

I have a list of array **exdate** which has some date. I want to exclude those dates and suggest the next available date from today. Date should not be random.

```
const exdate = ["24/08/2020", "8/8/2020"] //dates needs to be excluded [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

The newly generated date would be "25/08/2020" which is the closest one and not in the array.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538644/generate-random-date-but-exclude-some-dates-from-array-in-javascript) has a question that is generating a random date using **math.random** function but my scenario is different.

Comment: You might start by generating a date for today with that format, then test if it's in the array. Increment by one day until you find a missing date. There are many questions here on formatting and adding days to a date, what have you tried?

Comment: @RobG I tried the code from the previous post but it is generating random date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate inside a while loop and check if exdate contains the current date. If it doesnt contain the date, add 1 day to the current date and check it again. If the current date is not present inside the exdate array, exit the while loop and print the value.

A thing you might consider: What is the expected format of your dates? You should make sure it stays consistent. e.g. dont use leading 0s in front of months. My answer should point you into the right direction.

```js
exdate = ['24/8/2020', '8/8/2020'];


let currDate = new Date();
let dd = currDate.getDate();
let mm = currDate.getMonth() + 1;
let y = currDate.getFullYear();
let dateFormat = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
while (true) {
  dd = currDate.getDate();
  mm = currDate.getMonth() + 1;
  y = currDate.getFullYear();
  dateFormat = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
  if (!exdate.includes(dateFormat)) break;
  currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);

}
console.log(dateFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does what you are after and is quite simple:

```js
import moment from "moment";

// Constants
const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'

// Utils
const strToDate = (date) => moment(date, dateFormat)
const dateToStr = (date) => date.format(dateFormat)
const sortByMoment = (a, b) => b.diff(a)
const incrementDate = (date) => date.add(1, 'day')
const isToday = (date) => moment().isSame(date, 'day')

// Data
const exdate = ["17/08/2020", "24/08/2020", "8/8/2020"];

// Implementation
const sortNewestToOldest = (data) => data
  .map(strToDate)
  .sort(sortByMoment)
  
const nextAvailableDate = ([head]) => isToday(head) ? [dateToStr(incrementDate(head))] : [dateToStr(moment())]
```

`nextAvailableDate` check if todays date is in the `exdate` list, if yes return tomorrow, else return today. If you also had future dates in there that you need to accomodate for you could expand `isToday` to be `isTodayOrInTheFuture`. The moment functions you would need can all be found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).